# Fetching MAX id from SQL Server database causes exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, reader

I am fetching maximum `ID` from table `PatientInfo` using this code:

```
private void LoadID()
{
    string query = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PatientInfo";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txtid.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // other code
        }

        reader.Close();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Because I have to first check whether any record exist or not, I'm using `reader.HasRows`. After that the code should get the ID and put it to the textbox. But it's not. It's throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I can't figure it out why.

In my database I have one record inserted. But its still giving the same result in both the conditions (1. when I have no data in table and 2. When I have data in table)

Secondly, I am trying to manually enter data in the table but it is doing nothing and saying the following thing

[image]

and hence, no data is added

Comment: Please add the programming language used in this question i think it's C#

Comment: Using ExectueScalar could simplify your code quite a bit.

Comment: oops. Yeah its c#

Comment: @Carra. How will I check existence of data by using ExecuteScalar?

Comment: @user3837889: you don't - if there is absolutely no data in your table, then `.ExecuteScalar()` will return `NULL` - check for that and you're done

Comment: OH yes. I can do this. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ID` is not a field in your query, you have to alias your `MAX`

```
string query = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM PatientInfo";
```

Comment: And can you please also tell why can't I manually edit data in the table

Comment: @user3837889 I don't user that tool, plain SQL is your friend, but I bet that SSMS is validating your data against the Table, so check for nulls or data types

Comment: OK. Thanks for help